# How to install all identical versions of its Windows working environment on Mac? (React-Native)

Tags: windows, macos, react-native, installation, development-environment

I have my React-native application on my Windows pc.
I would like to install exactly the same working environment on my Mac
with identical versions of each element to build my app on Mac without a hitch.
I don't know at all how to do it or where to start.

What is the easiest way to do this by considering having the same versions?

I am novice, any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file in your project the versions should stay the same when you transfer to a different machine.  If you don't, you can create one using `npm shrinkwrap`

There's lots of little things that could cause problems, but generally if you do the following steps it should get you most of the way there:

1) install [react native on the mac](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)   `npm install -g react-native-cli`

2) copy your project code to the mac

3) run `npm install` from the root directory of the react native project

4) run `react-native link`

5) `cd ios` and run `pod install`

6) Double-click the *.xcworkspace file to open up the project in Xcode.

7) `cd ..` to return to the project directory

8) run `npm start -- --reset-cache` to launch the bundler

7) try to build in Xcode

Answer (score 0):

Using Git and Github (or equivalent) seems to be a long term solution

Create a repo, commi, push your project and clone it and the Mac.
Every time you do a modification on your PC, you commit, push and then pull it on your Mac.

All the versions are specified in **package.json**, so after an **npm install** your project should be exactly the same.